# How do I fix "perl is not recognized" on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl

I've set up a log file to pick up MySQL slow queries.

I've been unable to parse the file however. Linux makes this task seem very simple. In tutorials it seems as easy as:

```
 $ mysqldumpslow -s c -t 10
```

In Windows however, I'm not sure how you run Perl, located in: *G:\xampp\perl\bin* with the Perl Script *mysqldumpslow.pl*, located in: *G:\xampp\mysql\scripts*

I've tried to enter:

> G:\xampp\mysql\scripts\perl mysqldumpslow -s c -t 10

The command prompt returns something like "perl is not recognized".

Comment: Have you tried `G:\xampp\mysql\scripts\perl.exe`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Errm, you are using the wrong paths.

If perl.exe is located in G:\xampp\perl\bin and the mysql script in G:\xampp\mysql\scripts, you need:

```
> G:\xampp\perl\bin\perl G:\xampp\mysql\scripts\mysqldumpslow.pl -s c -t 10.
```

Of course, that's a very roundabout way of doing things, so instead, add perl to your PATH, and `cd` into the correct directory and then run it:

```
> set PATH=G:\xampp\perl\bin\;%PATH%  // Note: This can be added in the
                                      // System Control Panel.
> cd /d G:\xampp\mysql\scripts
> perl mysqldumpslow.pl -s c -t 10
```

Or even better, add perl to your known filetypes.

1. Go to Explorer -> Tools -> Folder
   Options -> File Types.
2. Click 'New', type `pl` for the
   extension field. Click Ok.
3. Find PL in your list, click Advanced. Under Actions, click 'New'.
4. For Action type `open`, for 'Application used to perform action' type:

   `G:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe -w "%1" %*`
5. Click Ok.

Now you can just run the script as:

```
> mysqldumpslow.pl -s c -t 10
```

As you would in Linux.

Quick note: Adding .pl files as known file types is roughly equivalent to Unix people adding

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

to the start of every perl script. In Windows you only need to add it once.

Second note: The `-w` turns on Warnings in the perl interpreter. You can leave out the `-w` if you wish.

Comment: Any Idea what this error means? "Can't Locate strict.pm in @INC (INC contains: .) on line 8." Line 8 reads "use strict".

Comment: It can't load the `strict.pm` perl module. `@INC` is where perl looks for modules. Currently, yours is set to the current directory, '.'. See http://www.wellho.net/mouth/588_Changing-INC-where-Perl-loads-its-modules.html for more info, or ask a new, separate question.

Comment: I posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185762/how-do-i-read-this-perl-script-with-windows-shell

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error by using the command:

```
set PATH=C:\perl\bin;%PATH%
```

Answer (score 0):

if your Perl interpreter perl.exe is located in `G:\xampp\perl\bin`, then use `G:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe`. For convenience of calling your Perl interpreter from anywhere , you can add the path `G:\xampp\perl\bin` into your PATH environment variable. To call your Perl script, try this

```
c:\> G:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe G:\xampp\mysql\scripts\mysqldumpslow.pl
```