# Why can't mysqldumpslow.pl find any Perl modules on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl

I'm trying to parse a MYSQL slow query log from the command line.

Upon entering this:

```
set PATH=G:\xampp\perl\bin\;%PATH%
cd /d G:\xampp\mysql\scripts
perl mysqldumpslow.pl -s c -t 10
```

The shell returns an error `can't locate strict.pm in @INC (@INC contains: .) at mysqldumpslow.pl at line 8. BEGIN failed`

In the `perl` directory in xampp, there is only one file `perl.exe`.

Am I missing perl modules/libraries? What do I need to read this log file?

Comment: Wow, that's a screwed-up `@INC`... what the heck did they do to their Perl distribution?

Comment: What does `perl -V` show? Can you load modules in other Perl scripts or is this a problem with just mysqldumpslow.pl?

Comment: perl -v shows perl v5.8.7, the some notes on documentation

Comment: brian d foy asked for `perl -V` -- that's with an upper-case V.  It's not the same as `perl -v`, with a lower-case v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to find the location of `strict.pm` in your perl installation and to add the directory to the [`PERL5LIB`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlrun#PERL5LIB) environment variable, or to invoke `perl` with the
`-I/path/to/strict.pm/directory` option (see [`perlfaq8`: How do I add a directory to my include path (@INC) at runtime?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-add-a-directory-to-my-include-path-INC-at-runtime-)).

If you find more unsatisfied dependencies, keep adding directories to `PERL5LIB` or with additional `-I` options until your program can run.

(Though eventually you will probably get tired of this and fix/reinstall perl.)

**UPDATE**: Looking through the 1.7.3 XAMPP distribution, all of the perl library files are located under `xampp\perl\lib` and `xampp\perl\site\lib`, so

```
    perl -IG:/xampp/perl/lib -IG:/xampp/perl/site/lib mysqldumpslow.pl -s c -t 10
```

is probably all that you need to do. YMMV if you have an older XAMPP distribution.

Comment: I'm running 1.7.0 Any recommendations. Do people really write YMMV? I'm so out of touch with these acronymns. :)

Comment: Prior to 1.7.2, perl was an "add-on" to XAMPP, but the directory structure (\perl\bin, \perl\lib, \perl\site\lib) is the same. Reinstall if you don't have those directories.

Answer (score 2):

Your Perl installation seems to have been messed up in one way or another. I am not familiar with xampp, but I have a hard time believing they bundled just the `perl.exe` without the rest of the distribution.

Under `G:\xampp\perl`, there should be subdirectories such as `lib`, `site` etc.

`strict` is a core pragma and its absence indicates that you do not have a proper Perl installation.

In fact, I just downloaded [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641) and it does contain `lib` and `site\lib` under `xampp\perl` (it is missing the documentation, but that is not essential to running Perl scripts).